Name the movie in which Godzilla, A Giant Bird, and a Robo are involved
I saw a movie in 2005 (but it was older than that) in which in the beginning, Godzilla and a Giant bird fight each other. The bird disappears for a while, then Godzilla enters a city and starts destroying the city, I don't remember why. After that the govt./policemen create a big robot to attack the Godzilla, and in the end the Giant bird comes again. Here Robo and Godzilla fight at the same time, air military and the Giant Bird fight. After some time, the Godzilla and the Giant Bird mix up, I don't know why/how, am a kid boss.
So what is the name of this movie?

Any other details that might help identification? Was it from around 2005 or older? Which country was it likely from?

no its not around 2005, its an old movie. and I don't know regarding country too, but its an English movie.

Sounds like Godzilla vs. Mechagodzilla II (1993)

@Oliver_C yes, it is. After seeing this video I recall it. Thanks, how to accept your answer.. :o

@santu47 Oliver_C has to post it as a proper answer first, then you can click on the check mark next to it.

@Oliver_C Sorry to steal the answer, but after 3 weeks this question needs to be closed.

Oliver_C gave a (seemingly correct) answer in a comment but refused to add it as a proper answer. So I'm going to post here for the sake of comleteness:

Sounds like Godzilla vs. Mechagodzilla II (1993)



The film featured the return of classic characters from the original series such as Rodan and Mechagodzilla, as well as introducing an infant Godzilla named BabyGodzilla. Although it shares a title with Godzilla vs. Mechagodzilla, the film is neither a remake nor a re-imagining of the earlier film. Despite its North American title, the film is not a sequel to the original Godzilla vs. Mechagodzilla, nor does it share any connections or similarities with the original.


Mechagodzilla II (1993) did not "introduce" Baby Godzilla.  Son of Godzilla (1967) did.  Just to set that straight. :o)

@JohnnyBones Well, tell it to Wikipedia, that would set it straight. ;-)

My bad.  Godzilla had 2 sons ("Minilla" and "Baby Godzilla"), though I don't remember the first one dying.
